Select only columns that have no duplicates considering groups
I have a rather large dataset with both long and short data inside: some columns have unique value given a subject and a visit, while other have multiple values.
The short data is duplicated to match the format of the long data, so that for some arbitrary number of columns the data have duplicated rows.
I'm looking for a way to automatically identify these columns and then shorten the dataset.
I already have a working solution but the code is very slow.
Is there a way to make it faster?
Ideally, the solution should also use the tidyverse and be contained in one pipeline.
Here is a reprex:
library(tidyverse)

#overly complicated data generation to match mine
n_id = 200
n_visit = 15
r = 20
N = n_id*n_visit*r
df = tibble(
  id=rep(1:n_id, each=n_visit*r),
  visit=rep(paste0("v", 1:n_visit), times=n_id*r),
) %>% 
  mutate(
    !!!set_names(rep(NA, 50), paste0("short",1:50)),
    !!!set_names(rep(NA, 50), paste0("long",1:50)),
    across(starts_with("short"), ~visit),
    across(starts_with("long"), ~rnorm(n())),
) %>% 
  arrange(id, visit)

df %>% summarise(a=length(unique(short1)), .by=c(id, visit)) %>% pull() %>% unique()
#> [1] 1
df %>% summarise(a=length(unique(long1)), .by=c(id, visit)) %>% pull() %>% unique()
#> [1] 20


#expected output
a = df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~length(unique(.x))), .by=c(id, visit))  %>% 
  select(id, visit, where(~all(.x==1))) %>% 
  names()

df %>% 
  select(all_of(a)) %>% 
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 3,000 × 52
#>       id visit short1 short2 short3 short4 short5 short6 short7 short8 short9
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1     1 v1    v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1    
#>  2     1 v10   v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10   
#>  3     1 v11   v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11   
#>  4     1 v12   v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12   
#>  5     1 v13   v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13   
#>  6     1 v14   v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14   
#>  7     1 v15   v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15   
#>  8     1 v2    v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2    
#>  9     1 v3    v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3    
#> 10     1 v4    v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4    
#> # ℹ 2,990 more rows
#> # ℹ 41 more variables: short10 <chr>, short11 <chr>, short12 <chr>,
#> #   short13 <chr>, short14 <chr>, short15 <chr>, short16 <chr>, short17 <chr>,
#> #   short18 <chr>, short19 <chr>, short20 <chr>, short21 <chr>, short22 <chr>,
#> #   short23 <chr>, short24 <chr>, short25 <chr>, short26 <chr>, short27 <chr>,
#> #   short28 <chr>, short29 <chr>, short30 <chr>, short31 <chr>, short32 <chr>,
#> #   short33 <chr>, short34 <chr>, short35 <chr>, short36 <chr>, …

Created on 2024-07-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Using data.table::uniqueN is a bit faster.
library(data.table)
system.time({
  u <- uniqueN(setDT(df)[,id:visit])
  a2 <- names(df)[c(TRUE, TRUE, sapply(3:ncol(df), \(i) {i <- c(1:2, i); uniqueN(df[,..i]) == u}))]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.61    0.09    0.45

Compare to:
#expected output
system.time(
  a <- df %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~length(unique(.x))), .by=c(id, visit))  %>% 
    select(id, visit, where(~all(.x==1))) %>% 
    names()
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.86    0.12    1.98

identical(a, a2)
#> [1] TRUE


Indeed, it is much faster, but I'd rather not add yet another dependency to my package.

Although, fast is subjective but I really doubt if dplyr is the right tool to make anything faster.
I have recently started exploring collapse package which is also faster in many cases. The syntax is very similar to dplyr so it is easy to get started.
temp_df <- df |> 
    fgroup_by(id, visit) |>
    fsummarise(across(short1:long50, \(x) fnunique(x))) 
  
get_vars(df, c(TRUE, TRUE, dapply(temp_df[-c(1:2)], \(x) all(x == 1)))) |>
    funique()

# A tibble: 3,000 × 52
#      id visit short1 short2 short3 short4 short5 short6 short7 short8 short9
#   <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
# 1     1 v1    v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1     v1    
# 2     1 v10   v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10    v10   
# 3     1 v11   v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11    v11   
# 4     1 v12   v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12    v12   
# 5     1 v13   v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13    v13   
# 6     1 v14   v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14    v14   
# 7     1 v15   v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15    v15   
# 8     1 v2    v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2     v2    
# 9     1 v3    v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3     v3    
#10     1 v4    v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4     v4    
# ℹ 2,990 more rows
# ℹ 41 more variables: short10 <chr>, short11 <chr>, short12 <chr>,
#   short13 <chr>, short14 <chr>, short15 <chr>, short16 <chr>, short17 <chr>,
#   short18 <chr>, short19 <chr>, short20 <chr>, short21 <chr>, short22 <chr>,
#   short23 <chr>, short24 <chr>, short25 <chr>, short26 <chr>, short27 <chr>,
#   short28 <chr>, short29 <chr>, short30 <chr>, short31 <chr>, short32 <chr>,
#   short33 <chr>, short34 <chr>, short35 <chr>, short36 <chr>, …
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

We can compare the solutions now.
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df_copy <- copy(df)
collapse_function <- function(df) {
  temp_df <- df |> 
    fgroup_by(id, visit) |>
    fsummarise(across(short1:long50, \(x) fnunique(x))) 
  
  get_vars(df, c(TRUE, TRUE, dapply(temp_df[-c(1:2)], \(x) all(x == 1)))) |>
    funique()
  
}
 
dplyr_function <- function(df) {
  a = df %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~length(unique(.x))), .by=c(id, visit))  %>% 
    select(id, visit, where(~all(.x==1))) %>% 
    names()
  
  df %>% 
    select(all_of(a)) %>% 
    distinct() 
}

data.table_function <- function(df) {
  u <- uniqueN(setDT(df)[,id:visit])
  a2 <- names(df)[c(TRUE, TRUE, sapply(3:ncol(df), \(i) {i <- c(1:2, i); uniqueN(df[,..i]) == u}))]
  unique(df[, ..a2])
}

When comparing against different solutions it fares well against dplyr solution but falls short than data.table. This could also because I am still learning this package and don't know the best functions to do the job.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr = dplyr_function(df), 
  data.table = data.table_function(df_copy), 
  collapse = collapse_function(df), 
  times = 10L
)

#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#      dplyr 2528.2535 2777.8296 2895.0289 2898.4619 2958.9916 3444.3321    10
# data.table  477.6706  498.5118  538.4991  519.4035  529.3705  686.3118    10
#   collapse  589.5543  601.7683  688.7736  616.8076  805.4987  933.2496    10


Indeed, dplyr is not the tool to make things fast, but I thought maybe my algorithm was not efficient. I'd rather not add yet another dependency to my package.
